# I started to learn javascript. How can I add another scroll function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

This is HTML-code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Welcome</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <header>
    <div id="menu" class="row no-gutter menu">
     <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-1">
      <img src="img/logo.png">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-8">
      <nav class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
      <ul class="p-2">
       <li>
        <a href="">Improves</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="">Projects</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a id="about" href="">About</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row no-gutter">
     <div class="hellopage">
      <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 hello">
      <font>
       Hello.
      </font>
      <br>
      <div class="mynameis">
       My name is
       <div class="name">
        DENIS,
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="whoami">
       I am a web-desihner, and front-end developer, and a person, who interested in IT.
      </div>
      <div class="quality">
       Quality is a main parametr for me.
      </div>
      <div class="classcol-md-5 offset-md-4">
       <button class="bnative1" id="button">
        FOLLOW ME
       </button> 
      </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- Второй блок -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div id="sb" class="row no-gutter sb">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 text-center whatcani">
     What can I offer for you?
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-1 pic1 ">
     <img src="img/adopt.png">
     <div class="txt1">
      <div class="top1">Adaptive Web-Design</div>
      <div>I always use adaptive</div>
      <div>design.Usually,web-site</div>
      <div>is an advertisment</div>
      <div>for big set of companies.</div>
      <div>It have to be focused on</div>
      <div>client and must be</div>
      <div>correctly displayed in all</div>
      <div>devices</div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-1 pic2">
     <img src="img/hands.png">
     <div class="txt2">
     <div class="top2">Indivigual aproach</div>
     <div>I always interact with</div>
     <div>the customer and ready</div>
     <div>to give some advice,</div>
     <div>based on my experience</div>
     <div>to make web-site better</div>
     <div>and user-friendly</div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-1 pic3">
     <img src="img/calendar.png">
     <div class="txt3">
     <div class="top3">Completion on time</div>
     <div>The project will be</div>
     <div>compleated on time,</div>
     <div>and a work plan will be</div>
     <div>provided for the</div>
     <div>customer</div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2 line">
     <hr>
    </div>
    
   </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Третий блок -->
    <div id="me" class="row no-gutter tb">
     <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-4 text-center  aboutme">
      About me
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 txtab">
      <div>I started my career as a system administrator(2016). At work I</div>
      <div>recieved a lot of skills, that helps me to deal every issue. Because</div>
      <div>there are exist an issues, that you can't solve by using internet. For</div>
      <div>example I worked with special software for MRI.</div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-1 whiteone">
      <img src="img/white.png">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 nowi">
      Now I am <span class="wd">WEB DESIGNER</span>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-9 offset-md-1 person">
      And a person, who ready to make <span class="cool">COOL</span> web-site for you.
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-7 d-flex flex-row-reverse">
      <img class="whitetwo" src="img/white.png">
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Четвертый блок -->
    <div class="row no-gutter fob">
     <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-3 text-center inmy">
      In my projects I use
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-1 desone">
      <img src="img/gapps.png">
      <div class="tech1">
       <div>I use graphical applications to</div>
       <div>make a template for your website.</div>
       <div>This is the first step. Here we can</div>
       <div>coose a colors, that will be used</div>
       <div>in web-site</div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 destwo">
      <img src="img/site.png">
      <div class="tech1">
       <div>To make web-page, I use HTML,CSS, JS, Less. Here I</div>
       <div>can make animation, that can make your website</div>
       <div>alive.</div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 technologies">
      <div>I always <span class="devmy">DEVELOPE</span> myself, learn new technologies and</div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-7 inmy"><span class="use">USE</span> it in my projects</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Футер -->
    <div class="row no-gutter foot">
     
      <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-1 social">
       <img src="img/email.png">
       den_lupanov@mail.ru
       <div class="fb">
        <img src="img/facebook.png">
        https://www.facebook.com/den.necris
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 offset-md-5 gototop">
       <img id="up" src="img/up.png">
      </div>
     
    </div> 
   </div>
  </div> 
 </body>   
</html>
'''
```

I have a code:

```js
window.onload = function(){
 // Изменение цвета при наведении на кнопку
 var button = document.getElementById("button");
 button.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(){
  button.classList.remove("bnative1");
  button.classList.add("buttonclass1");
 });
 button.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){
  button.classList.remove("buttonclass1");
  button.classList.add("bnative1");
 })
 // Scroll to the first element(Works ok)
 document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", scrollToElement);
 function scrollToElement(e){
 element = document.getElementById("sb");
 element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: "start",});
 }
 //Scroll to another element(ERROR)
 document.getElementById("up").addEventListener("click", scrollToTop);
 function scrollToTop(e){
  top = document.getElementById("menu");
  top.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: "start"});
 }
 }

'''
```

Finally, when I click on the second element for scrolling, in debugger I recieve an error:"Uncaught TypeError: top.scrollIntoView is not a function
    at HTMLImageElement.scrollToTop (script.js:22)". It should works properly, but I don't understand why it doen not working

Comment: Add your html too, most probably there is no element with id `menu`

Comment: Could you please include your HTML code?

Comment: Ok, I added HTML-code

Comment: This is strange, it should works like scroll on button. I suppose, that I cant use two scroll functions in window.olnoad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just needed to define "top".  add var and your code works!

```js
window.onload = function(){


}

 // Изменение цвета при наведении на кнопку
 var button = document.getElementById("button");
 button.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(){
  button.classList.remove("bnative1");
  button.classList.add("buttonclass1");
 });
 button.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){
  button.classList.remove("buttonclass1");
  button.classList.add("bnative1");
 })
 // Scroll to the first element(Works ok)
 document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", scrollToElement);
 function scrollToElement(e){
 element = document.getElementById("sb");
 element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: "start",});
 }
 //Scroll to another element(ERROR)
 document.getElementById("up").addEventListener("click", scrollToTop);
 function scrollToTop(e){
  var top = document.getElementById("menu");
  top.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: "start"});
 }
```

```html
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Welcome</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <header>
    <div id="menu" class="row no-gutter menu">
     <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-1">
      <img src="img/logo.png">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-8">
      <nav class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
      <ul class="p-2">
       <li>
        <a href="">Improves</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="">Projects</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a id="about" href="">About</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row no-gutter">
     <div class="hellopage">
      <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 hello">
      <font>
       Hello.
      </font>
      <br>
      <div class="mynameis">
       My name is
       <div class="name">
        DENIS,
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="whoami">
       I am a web-desihner, and front-end developer, and a person, who interested in IT.
      </div>
      <div class="quality">
       Quality is a main parametr for me.
      </div>
      <div class="classcol-md-5 offset-md-4">
       <button class="bnative1" id="button">
        FOLLOW ME
       </button> 
      </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- Второй блок -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div id="sb" class="row no-gutter sb">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 text-center whatcani">
     What can I offer for you?
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-1 pic1 ">
     <img src="img/adopt.png">
     <div class="txt1">
      <div class="top1">Adaptive Web-Design</div>
      <div>I always use adaptive</div>
      <div>design.Usually,web-site</div>
      <div>is an advertisment</div>
      <div>for big set of companies.</div>
      <div>It have to be focused on</div>
      <div>client and must be</div>
      <div>correctly displayed in all</div>
      <div>devices</div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-1 pic2">
     <img src="img/hands.png">
     <div class="txt2">
     <div class="top2">Indivigual aproach</div>
     <div>I always interact with</div>
     <div>the customer and ready</div>
     <div>to give some advice,</div>
     <div>based on my experience</div>
     <div>to make web-site better</div>
     <div>and user-friendly</div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-1 pic3">
     <img src="img/calendar.png">
     <div class="txt3">
     <div class="top3">Completion on time</div>
     <div>The project will be</div>
     <div>compleated on time,</div>
     <div>and a work plan will be</div>
     <div>provided for the</div>
     <div>customer</div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2 line">
     <hr>
    </div>
    
   </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Третий блок -->
    <div id="me" class="row no-gutter tb">
     <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-4 text-center  aboutme">
      About me
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 txtab">
      <div>I started my career as a system administrator(2016). At work I</div>
      <div>recieved a lot of skills, that helps me to deal every issue. Because</div>
      <div>there are exist an issues, that you can't solve by using internet. For</div>
      <div>example I worked with special software for MRI.</div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-1 whiteone">
      <img src="img/white.png">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 nowi">
      Now I am <span class="wd">WEB DESIGNER</span>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-9 offset-md-1 person">
      And a person, who ready to make <span class="cool">COOL</span> web-site for you.
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-7 d-flex flex-row-reverse">
      <img class="whitetwo" src="img/white.png">
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Четвертый блок -->
    <div class="row no-gutter fob">
     <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-3 text-center inmy">
      In my projects I use
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-1 desone">
      <img src="img/gapps.png">
      <div class="tech1">
       <div>I use graphical applications to</div>
       <div>make a template for your website.</div>
       <div>This is the first step. Here we can</div>
       <div>coose a colors, that will be used</div>
       <div>in web-site</div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 destwo">
      <img src="img/site.png">
      <div class="tech1">
       <div>To make web-page, I use HTML,CSS, JS, Less. Here I</div>
       <div>can make animation, that can make your website</div>
       <div>alive.</div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 technologies">
      <div>I always <span class="devmy">DEVELOPE</span> myself, learn new technologies and</div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-7 inmy"><span class="use">USE</span> it in my projects</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Футер -->
    <div class="row no-gutter foot">
     
      <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-1 social">
       <img src="img/email.png">
       den_lupanov@mail.ru
       <div class="fb">
        <img src="img/facebook.png">
        https://www.facebook.com/den.necris
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 offset-md-5 gototop">
       <img id="up" src="img/up.png">
      </div>
     
    </div> 
   </div>
```

Comment: Hello, you was right, "top" have been reserved, when I chanded it, everything start working properly

Answer (score 0):

Other than using it like that it might be better to make it one function and use it in the HTML.

The following code should work like a charm:

```
function scrollSmoothTo(elementId) {
var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
element.scrollIntoView({ block: 'start',  behavior: 'smooth' });
}
```

And, in HTML use it like that:

```
<a class="btn-outline-light" onclick="scrollSmoothTo('work')">See our work</a>
```